# Não está retornando o segundo parâmetro

Tags: php, htaccess, mod-rewrite

Estou desenvolvendo uma api. Basicamente ela requisita uma página de acordo com a solicitação.
Exemplo: `http://localhost/mod/<name>/<version>`
o problema está sendo o /version. Eu fiz o htaccess dessa maneira:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule /mod/(.*) /mod.php?name=$1
RewriteRule /mod/(.*)/(.*) /mod.php?name=$1&version=$2
RewriteRule /modpack/(.*) /modpack.php?slug=$1
RewriteRule /modpack/(.*)/(.*) /modpack.php?slug=$1&build=$2
```

Porém se eu requisito por exemplo /mod/test/1.0 o no `$_GET['version']` diz que o index version é nulo.

```
<?php
    echo "It works! name=" . $_GET['name'] . ',version=' .$_GET['version'];
?>
```

Usei esta linha:     `RewriteRule /mod/(.*)/(.*) /mod.php?name=$1&version=$2`

Mas ele coloca a version junto com o name:

> Notice: Undefined index: version in C:\xampp\htdocs\mod.php on line 2
>   It works! name=test/1.0,version=

**O mesmo acontece no `/modpack/<slug>/<build>`**

```
RewriteRule /modpack/(.*)/(.*) /modpack.php?slug=$1&build=$2
```

Comment: sim ( só pra completar o comentário)

Comment: Deve ter de fazer um explode, o get não entra mais (tanto quanto sei) nesse formato... `explode('/', URL)` , depois terá os segmentos e continua a partir daí... Só não respondo porque não tenho 100% de certeza de que esta é a unica/melhor maneira de fazer

Comment: Até pensei em utilizar o explode mas o problema é se algum usuário colocar uma / no version ai vai bugar o sistema.

Comment: Pode retirar as `/` sempre do fim, `$url = rtrim('/', URL)` antes de fazer o explode

Comment: irei vou tentar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso está acontecendo porquê .* é uma regex muito gulosa, pois casa com tudo, inclusive com a barra /, por isso que vc não consegue separar os parâmetros.

O correto é vc melhorar essa regex. Exemplo: `([^\/]+)` (para não casar a /)

```
RewriteRule /modpack/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+) /modpack.php?slug=$1&build=$2
```

Comment: Ok. Fiz a troca porém a `$_GET['version']`está retornando vazia

Comment: http://prntscr.com/dg6je8

Comment: RewriteRule /modpack/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+) /modpack.php?slug=$1&build=$2

Comment: Realmente funcionou mesmo. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.